# Other Linker Flags project not building

Tags: ios, cocoapods, flags

I recently add to work with cocoa pods in order to play with the google map sdk.
It was the first time I used pods so I followed the tutorial. in the end, launching the workspace worked but the project didn't build. I've read that this could be related to "other linker flags" in the build setting, and that deleting all flags could help. now my project build but some of the stuff arent (example, the original mapView I had doesn't load...) could it be related, and how to solve this?

I had a bunch of stuff inside the other flags but I don't know what is it for...
Any help would be appreciated.

I cloned my project again, without the pods, but the other linker flags aren't back in here... which is odd

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: there is no error. I managed to clone the repos again and the map was there, but not the other linker flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone any project again, all the settings of master will come back again. It is kind of git reset hard. Follow following steps for integrating your google maps sdk

1. sudo gem install cocoapods.
2. pod init
3. open Xcode -a podfile
   Your podfile should look like this [swift]:

   ---

   ```
   use_frameworks! 
   platform :ios, ‘8.0’
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   ```

   ---
4. Save the podfile
5. remove all the local dependencies mentioned in your podfile from target folder.
6. change to #import
7. use $inherited in your linker Search Path, Build Settings.
8. Now do pod install, and then pod update.

Comment: could you specify what you mean for steps 5 and 6 ? local dependencies from podfile? and change to #import?

Comment: managed to make it work with a new project. My issue is more about the way installing pods on existing project create Match OLinker error. It seems to come from the linker flags. ?

Comment: 5. If you have manually added some dependencies, then remove them.

Comment: 6. #import "AFNetworking.h" will change to #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworkig.h>

Comment: If you have a problem on your existing problem, then try reinstalling the pod in the above way. I was stuck on the pod installation for 1 week, this way worked at last. I installed on existing project. DO CHECK ALL YOUR SEARCH PATHS IN BUILD SETTINGS. Xcode should get the dependencies thru pods, not target